# Store strings with spaces into Arrays Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, whitespace

I'm trying to store a string with spaces into an array. I've used IFS="" and noticed that by doing this. my array_size is 1 although I have multiple strings. Is there a way to fix this?

the code i'm using

```
size=0
declare -a new
for t in ${temp};
do
  new[size++]=$t
done;
for n in ${new[@]};
do
  echo $n end
done;
```

my output is..

```
my string 1
my string 2
another string 3
another string 3 end
```

my desired output would like something like this..

```
 my string 1 end
 my string 2 end
 another string 3 end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate over input with each item on separate line you have to set IFS to line feed.

You can do following to read the items to an array.

```
declare -a new
IFS=$'\n'
new=${temp}
```